# find overlaps using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

file1 :

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
1    20   10   -
1    25   30   +
2    50   40   -
2    60   70   +
```

file2:

```
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    25   5   -     e1    e2
1    20   30   +    e4    e24
2    45   35   -    e9    e12
2    55   75   +    e10    e21
```

I need to check for 3 conditions :
1) check if element in col0 is same (1 ==1)

2) if yes then check the col3 if its  - or +, if - then the col1 value will be higher than col2 and the opposite if its +,

3) check if the range is within the col1 and col2 from file2 i.e 
   in row two 25-30 fall within the range 20-30 if all conditions met, out put rows in file 1 and col4 and col5 in file 2 (which are some meta info)

```
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    20   10   -    e1    e2
1    25   30   +    e4    e24
2    50   40   -    e9    e12
2    60   70   +    e10   e21
```

simple python code would have a condition like this

```
for i in file1:
    for j in file2:
        if i[1]<j[1] and i[2]<j[2] and i[0]==j[0]:
           print j
```

not sure how to account for the sign, How can i achieve this using pandas, or pandas would not be a right approach?

Comment: Clarifications: (1) In 3) "check if the range is within...", here "the range" means the range bounded by `col1` and `col2` in file1, and you want to see if that range is within the corresponding `col1`/`col2` range in file2?    (2) In 1) is it sufficient to match row by row?  For example, row 2 in file1 has `col0==1`, but there are rows in file2 with `col0==1`.  Does file1, row 2 range need to be within both ranges with matching `col0` values in file2?    (3) In 3), "fall within the range", are the bounds on both ends inclusive?  (e.g. range 20-30 would qualify as being inside the range 20-30?

Comment: Also, is `col3` always guaranteed to be the same, row-wise, for `file1` and `file2`?

Comment: @andrew_reece (1) yes within the range or on them, (2) yes (3) yes both ends inclusive and finally col3 will be same for the file1 and file2.

Comment: In your expected output, you include row 3, but if I understand correctly, this should be excluded: 40-50 range is outside 35-45 range.  Am I getting that right?

Comment: yes, it should be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

**Generate sample data provided by OP**

```
# copy file1 data from OP, then run:
df1 = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index()

# copy file2 data from OP, then run:
df2 = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index()
```

**Merge and filter data**

```
# merge data on row index and col0 value
df3 = (df1.merge(df2.drop('col3',1), on=['index','col0'], suffixes=('_1','_2'))
          .drop('index',1))

# sort range cols from file2
df3[['col1_2','col2_2']] = df3[['col1_2','col2_2']].apply(sorted, axis='columns')

# filter based on file1 range within file2 range, drop extra cols
df3 = (df3.loc[df3.col1_1.between(df3.col1_2, df3.col2_2) & df3.col2_1.between(df3.col1_2, df3.col2_2)]
          .drop(['col1_2','col2_2'], 1))
print(df3)
```

**Output**

```
   col0  col1_1  col2_1 col3 col4 col5
0     1      20      10    -   e1   e2
1     1      25      30    +   e4  e24
3     2      60      70    +  e10  e21
```

Comment: let me try this on my real data

Comment: get this error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: Can you confirm my answer works on the sample data you provided?  If so, that suggests there are characteristics to your actual data that aren't represented in the example cases you've given.  If you update your example data to include missing edge cases, I can have another look.  It's also possible that this solution has simply uncovered a separate issue in your data, in which case I'd suggest accepting this answer and opening a new post.

Comment: i accepted your answer as it works on the data i gave, what does this error mean could you please explain so that I can look for red flags.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what the error indicates yet.  But happy to help "offline" - send me a chat or message with the full error text (including which line triggered the error), and some actual data, if you can share it.  I can have a look later this evening.